# Understanding derivation of the Sherman–Morrison formula

Tags: linear-algebra

On the internet I have seen a derivation of the Sherman-Morrison formula for rank-1 modifications in which $(A + uv^T)x = b$ is solved by introducing a new variable $y = v^Tx$ and then solving the system of equations

$$
\begin{align}
& Ax & + & uy & = b \\
& v^T& - &  y & = 0
\end{align}
$$

I think this is a really nice solution, but I don't really understand the intuition for doing this. I thought about it a bit and I guess by setting $y = v^T x$ we solve for $x$ and the scalar product $v^Tx$ from which we can find find the parts of the new system which are determined by $A$ and the parts which are termined by $uv^T$. I wouldn't really have though of this because to me it seems a bit like we are doing "magic" because I would think that both systems have the same amount of information, so why is a lot easier to solve the modified one? Is this a common technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve for $y=v^Tx$. It has to be solved together with $Ax+uy=b$. By augmenting with the extra variable $y$, it can be represented as block matrix equation,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & u \\
v^T & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
So now you can use the formula for block matrix inversion. But if you know how the block matrix inversion works, then it is not necessary to introduce $y$. You just need to keep track of where $v^Tx$ is in the derivation.
$$
\begin{aligned}
(A+uv^T)x &= b \\
Ax &= b - uv^Tx &  &\text{move}\ uv^Tx\ \text{to RHS}\\
x &= A^{-1}b - A^{-1}uv^Tx & (1)\ &\text{left multiply by}\ A^{-1}\\
v^Tx &= v^TA^{-1}b - v^TA^{-1}uv^Tx & &\text{left multiply by}\ v^T\\
(1+v^TA^{-1}u)v^Tx&=v^TA^{-1}b & &\text{gather}\ v^Tx\ \text{on LHS}\\
v^Tx&={v^TA^{-1}b\over 1+v^TA^{-1}u} & &\text{solve}\ v^Tx\\
\therefore x&=A^{-1}b - A^{-1}u{v^TA^{-1}b\over 1+v^TA^{-1}u} & &\text{plug in }\ v^Tx\ \text{to}\ (1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!